# taskbar - bring last window to front immediately instead of hover when multiple windows are open

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, taskbar

I had this behavior in windows 7. I don't know if it was default or if it was something I setup since I had windows 7 installed for years and years. 
I've installed windows 10 and am trying to get the same behavior.

Example: You have multiple notepad files open. So when you go to the taskbar and click, it only shows you the hover preview. It doesn't bring forward the last window you used.

I don't want to turn hover off, but I do want it to bring forward the last used window when I click on the icon. If you continue to click on the icon, it will cycle through all of the windows, bringing each of them forward.

I can't figure out the proper search keywords to find anything on google about this. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally figured out what I did in windows 7 to fix this issue. This fix still works for windows 10 as well. http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16334/make-the-taskbar-buttons-switch-to-the-last-active-window-in-windows-7/